# Safari 14 "safari cannot download this file"

Tags: javascript, safari

Generating a file with javascript and being able to download it has stopped working in Safari 14.6 IOS.

```
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.download = filename;
link.href = 'data:text/x-vcard;charset=utf-8,' + content;
link.click();
```

It works with Android , and in desktop.

Any workaround?

I tried this one with no luck:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
var out = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
reader.onload = function(e) {
    window.location.href = reader.result;
}
reader.readAsDataURL(out);
// var blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: "application/pdf" });
var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(out);
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = fileURL;
a.target = '_blank';
a.download = 'lkn_' + id + '.pdf';
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
```

Comment: looks like you are downloading from a url/ajax (`response.data`) if it's a regular GET request then maybe you can just try to set the url to `link.href = url`

Comment: hi!, the first example is just like that, dont it?

Comment: i ended up solving it. The file was badly formatted , resulting in safar  not allowing it to download.